# Extract a delimited list from a string inside brackets RegEx Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have seen quite a few regex questions out there that are similar but none seem to provide the correct handling of my odd situation. I have a list of strings that looks like the following:

```
['[Business Layer~Project Owning Org~Proj Owning Dept ID]', '[Business Layer~Project Owning Org~Proj Owning Org Name]', '[Business Layer~Project~Proj No]', '[Business Layer~Project~Proj Name]', "([Business Layer~Project~Proj No]) || COALESCE((' - ' || ([Business Layer~Project~Proj Name])), ' - ')", '[Project Assignment Fact~Task~Task No]', '[Project Assignment Fact~Task~Task Name]', "([Project Assignment Fact~Task~Task No]) || COALESCE((' - ' || ([Project Assignment Fact~Task~Task Name])), ' - ')", "([Business Layer~Project~Proj No]) || COALESCE((' - ' || ([Project Assignment Fact~Task~Task No])), ' - ') || COALESCE((' - ' || ([Project Assignment Fact~Task~Task Name])), ' - ')", '[Business Layer~Project Cost~Short Code Alias]', '[Business Layer~Expenditure Type~Expenditure Category Name]', '[Business Layer~Expenditure Type~Expenditure Type Parent Code]', '[Business Layer~Expenditure Type~Expend Type Desc]', '[Business Layer~Expenditure Owning Org~Exp Owning Org Name]', '[Business Layer~Transaction Source~Trans Source]', '[Business Layer~Employee~Employee Name]', '[Business Layer~Project Cost~Expend Comment]', '[Business Layer~Project Cost~PO No]', '[Business Layer~Project Cost~PV Invoice No]', '[Business Layer~Vendor~Vendor Name]', '[Business Layer~Scenario~Scenario Name]', '[Business Layer~ERS Employee~ERS Employee Name]', '[Business Layer~ERS Employee~ERS Employee Number]', '[Business Layer~Project Cost~Vehicle Tag No]', '[Business Layer~Project Cost~Vehicle Make]', '[Business Layer~Project Cost~Vehicle Model]', '[Business Layer~Project Cost~Vehicle Mileage]', '[Business Layer~Project Type~Proj Type Code]', '[Business Layer~GL Period~GL Period Start Date]', '[Business Layer~Project Cost~Burdened Cost Amt]']
```

As you can see, some of the strings are quite messy. i.e.:

```
([Business Layer~Project~Proj No]) || COALESCE((' - ' || ([Business Layer~Project~Proj Name])), ' - ')
```

I want to extract what is in the brackets as a list. For the messy one above, the ideal output would be a nested list like:

```
[['Business Layer', 'Project', 'Proj No'], ['Business Layer', 'Project', 'Proj Name']]
```

I have tried a few different Regex solutions from various similar questions with no success. Some unsuccessful examples:

```
# This one is close, but only accounts for 1 list
for i in test:
    result = re.findall("([^(~)]+)(?!.*\()+", i)
    print(result)


# Yields a blank list AND more importantly, some of these are longer than 3.
for i in test:
    result = re.findall("(\[.*?\]\~\[.*?\]\~\[.*?\])", i)
    print(result)


# This captures the beginning but not the end

^\[([^~]+)

# This essentially captures everything but what I want

[^~]+(?=\[.*?\]*$)
```

Please let me know what you think. I get confused with regex

Comment: I think this is not something you want to be tackling with regex. You probably want to match the brackets and extract the text based on that, which is something you simply cannot in with regex reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cents:

```py
list(map(lambda y: [x.split('~') for x in re.findall(r'\[([^\].*\[]*)\]', y)], all_strings))
```

where `all_strings` is the list of string in the question plus `'["if ([Business Layer~Scenario~Scenario Name] = ''Budget 2013'' and [Business Layer~GL Period~GL Year Number] = 2013) Then ([Business Layer~GL Balances~Period Net DR Amt]-[Business Layer~GL Balances~Period Net CR Amt]) else (0)", ''if'']'`.

Here the result for each string in `all_strings`:

```sh
[Business Layer~Project Owning Org~Proj Owning Dept ID] --> [['Business Layer', 'Project Owning Org', 'Proj Owning Dept ID']]
[Business Layer~Project Owning Org~Proj Owning Org Name] --> [['Business Layer', 'Project Owning Org', 'Proj Owning Org Name']]
[Business Layer~Project~Proj No] --> [['Business Layer', 'Project', 'Proj No']]
[Business Layer~Project~Proj Name] --> [['Business Layer', 'Project', 'Proj Name']]
([Business Layer~Project~Proj No]) || COALESCE((' - ' || ([Business Layer~Project~Proj Name])), ' - ') --> [['Business Layer', 'Project', 'Proj No'], ['Business Layer', 'Project', 'Proj Name']]
[Project Assignment Fact~Task~Task No] --> [['Project Assignment Fact', 'Task', 'Task No']]
[Project Assignment Fact~Task~Task Name] --> [['Project Assignment Fact', 'Task', 'Task Name']]
([Project Assignment Fact~Task~Task No]) || COALESCE((' - ' || ([Project Assignment Fact~Task~Task Name])), ' - ') --> [['Project Assignment Fact', 'Task', 'Task No'], ['Project Assignment Fact', 'Task', 'Task Name']]
([Business Layer~Project~Proj No]) || COALESCE((' - ' || ([Project Assignment Fact~Task~Task No])), ' - ') || COALESCE((' - ' || ([Project Assignment Fact~Task~Task Name])), ' - ') --> [['Business Layer', 'Project', 'Proj No'], ['Project Assignment Fact', 'Task', 'Task No'], ['Project Assignment Fact', 'Task', 'Task Name']]
[Business Layer~Project Cost~Short Code Alias] --> [['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'Short Code Alias']]
[Business Layer~Expenditure Type~Expenditure Category Name] --> [['Business Layer', 'Expenditure Type', 'Expenditure Category Name']]
[Business Layer~Expenditure Type~Expenditure Type Parent Code] --> [['Business Layer', 'Expenditure Type', 'Expenditure Type Parent Code']]
[Business Layer~Expenditure Type~Expend Type Desc] --> [['Business Layer', 'Expenditure Type', 'Expend Type Desc']]
[Business Layer~Expenditure Owning Org~Exp Owning Org Name] --> [['Business Layer', 'Expenditure Owning Org', 'Exp Owning Org Name']]
[Business Layer~Transaction Source~Trans Source] --> [['Business Layer', 'Transaction Source', 'Trans Source']]
[Business Layer~Employee~Employee Name] --> [['Business Layer', 'Employee', 'Employee Name']]
[Business Layer~Project Cost~Expend Comment] --> [['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'Expend Comment']]
[Business Layer~Project Cost~PO No] --> [['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'PO No']]
[Business Layer~Project Cost~PV Invoice No] --> [['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'PV Invoice No']]
[Business Layer~Vendor~Vendor Name] --> [['Business Layer', 'Vendor', 'Vendor Name']]
[Business Layer~Scenario~Scenario Name] --> [['Business Layer', 'Scenario', 'Scenario Name']]
[Business Layer~ERS Employee~ERS Employee Name] --> [['Business Layer', 'ERS Employee', 'ERS Employee Name']]
[Business Layer~ERS Employee~ERS Employee Number] --> [['Business Layer', 'ERS Employee', 'ERS Employee Number']]
[Business Layer~Project Cost~Vehicle Tag No] --> [['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'Vehicle Tag No']]
[Business Layer~Project Cost~Vehicle Make] --> [['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'Vehicle Make']]
[Business Layer~Project Cost~Vehicle Model] --> [['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'Vehicle Model']]
[Business Layer~Project Cost~Vehicle Mileage] --> [['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'Vehicle Mileage']]
[Business Layer~Project Type~Proj Type Code] --> [['Business Layer', 'Project Type', 'Proj Type Code']]
[Business Layer~GL Period~GL Period Start Date] --> [['Business Layer', 'GL Period', 'GL Period Start Date']]
[Business Layer~Project Cost~Burdened Cost Amt] --> [['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'Burdened Cost Amt']]
["if ([Business Layer~Scenario~Scenario Name] = Budget 2013 and [Business Layer~GL Period~GL Year Number] = 2013) Then ([Business Layer~GL Balances~Period Net DR Amt]-[Business Layer~GL Balances~Period Net CR Amt]) else (0)", if] --> [['Business Layer', 'Scenario', 'Scenario Name'], ['Business Layer', 'GL Period', 'GL Year Number'], ['Business Layer', 'GL Balances', 'Period Net DR Amt'], ['Business Layer', 'GL Balances', 'Period Net CR Amt']]
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this is it. Doing a run on all now. Is this a way to not have a double nested list? I know list(map) kinda of puts it that way automatically

Comment: Hi, `map` is used here only to apply the function to extract lists with matches to a single string. The result of `map` is a list collecting all the results of applying `[x.split('~') for x in re.findall(r'\[([^\].*\[]*)\]', y)]` to each string in `all_strings`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something different - just search for characters `a-Z` and space.

If `string_list` is your list from the question:

```
import re

for s in string_list:
    print(re.findall(r"[A-Z][\sa-zA-Z]*", s))
```

Prints:

```
['Business Layer', 'Project Owning Org', 'Proj Owning Dept ID']
['Business Layer', 'Project Owning Org', 'Proj Owning Org Name']
['Business Layer', 'Project', 'Proj No']
['Business Layer', 'Project', 'Proj Name']
['Business Layer', 'Project', 'Proj No', 'COALESCE', 'Business Layer', 'Project', 'Proj Name']
['Project Assignment Fact', 'Task', 'Task No']
['Project Assignment Fact', 'Task', 'Task Name']
['Project Assignment Fact', 'Task', 'Task No', 'COALESCE', 'Project Assignment Fact', 'Task', 'Task Name']
['Business Layer', 'Project', 'Proj No', 'COALESCE', 'Project Assignment Fact', 'Task', 'Task No', 'COALESCE', 'Project Assignment Fact', 'Task', 'Task Name']
['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'Short Code Alias']
['Business Layer', 'Expenditure Type', 'Expenditure Category Name']
['Business Layer', 'Expenditure Type', 'Expenditure Type Parent Code']
['Business Layer', 'Expenditure Type', 'Expend Type Desc']
['Business Layer', 'Expenditure Owning Org', 'Exp Owning Org Name']
['Business Layer', 'Transaction Source', 'Trans Source']
['Business Layer', 'Employee', 'Employee Name']
['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'Expend Comment']
['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'PO No']
['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'PV Invoice No']
['Business Layer', 'Vendor', 'Vendor Name']
['Business Layer', 'Scenario', 'Scenario Name']
['Business Layer', 'ERS Employee', 'ERS Employee Name']
['Business Layer', 'ERS Employee', 'ERS Employee Number']
['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'Vehicle Tag No']
['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'Vehicle Make']
['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'Vehicle Model']
['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'Vehicle Mileage']
['Business Layer', 'Project Type', 'Proj Type Code']
['Business Layer', 'GL Period', 'GL Period Start Date']
['Business Layer', 'Project Cost', 'Burdened Cost Amt']
```

Comment: This is good. Close but no cigar. The problem is some of them are essentially long code snippets. For a different example:
```["if ([Business Layer~Scenario~Scenario Name] = 'Budget 2013' and [Business Layer~GL Period~GL Year Number] = 2013) Then ([Business Layer~GL Balances~Period Net DR Amt]-[Business Layer~GL Balances~Period Net CR Amt]) else (0)", 'if']``` which would yield quite a few unwanted "ifs, whens, budegets, etc"

Comment: @SamDean This seems to me like `X-Y` problem. Do you try to parse javascript/some other language with regex?